# Tree searching with unlabeled nodes

Tags: ocaml

If I have an unlabeled tree with integer leafs. So say Node( Node(1,2) , Node(2,3) ). I want to have a function that takes this unlabeled tree and turn it into a labeled tree where the node data value is the sum of the two leafs. So for this example Node( Node(1, 3, 2), 8, Node(2, 5, 3)). How would I go about doing this if the unlabeled tree can be unbalanced? I've tried thinking about a solution using the depth of each node/leaf but I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: Please add code, like existing type definitions and your current attempt at a solution. Also, at first glance, whether tree is balanced or not seems not very important for computing the sum recursively and building a labeled tree.

Comment: You should check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question on Stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the tree is balanced or not has no impact on annotating the tree.

As @ivg points out, your example code, `Node( Node(1,2) , Node(2,3) )`, doesn't make sense because the nodes are storing both child nodes and numbers, which have different types. The correct way to do this is:

```
type tree =
  | Leaf of int (* Leaves store numbers *)
  | Node of tree * tree

let tree = Node(Node(Leaf 1, Leaf 2), Node(Leaf 2, Leaf 3))
```

A tree where each node can have a label, including the inner nodes, could be encoded as

```
type tree' =
  | Leaf' of int
  | Node' of tree' * int * tree'

let tree' = Node'(Node'(Leaf' 1, 3, Leaf' 2), 8, Node'(Leaf' 2, 5, Leaf' 3))
```

To annotate a tree:

```
let weight : tree' -> int = function
  | Leaf' n -> n (* The weight of a leaf is its data *)
  | Node'(_, n, _) -> n (* The weight of a node is its middle value *)

let rec annot_tree : tree -> tree' = function
  | Leaf n -> Leaf' n (* Base case *)
  | Node(l, r) ->
      let labeled_l = annot_tree l in (* Annotate left child *)
      let labeled_r = annot_tree r in (* Annotate right child *)
      Node'(labeled_l, weight labeled_l + weight labeled_r, labeled_r)
```

Comment: This is not an unlabeled tree. This is a labeled tree where only leaf nodes are labeled. A rarely used tree (for example, see B-tree).

Comment: I'm downvoting your question since it confuses terminology. I will happily revert downvoting once you will fix it and stop calling labeled trees unlabeled. Otherwise, your answer is good, though in general, we're trying not to solve students homeworks, but instead help them to understand the problem, so that they can solve it themselves. Otherwise, we're ruining the education process. I also hope, that reading my answer and following the links, or just googling, will help you to resolve the terminology issue :)

Comment: Upvoted, since this answers the question and doesn't go into unnecessary tangents about combinatorial terminology.

Comment: It is not about combinatorial terminology, it is about spreading fallacy :) And mathematics requires us to be concrete in the terminology. 
@TAH, I've suggested an edit which makes your posting less incorrect, I was assuming that it should go through your review, but it was automatically accepted. Please feel free to revert it or revise, but please keep in mind mathematical and common definition of what tree is. Let's not confuse students anymore :) Meantime, revoking my own downvote.

Answer (score -1):

## Terminology

First of all let's figure out what is a labeled and unlabeled tree and how they could be represented as data structures.

> If I have an unlabeled tree with integer leafs.

There is no such thing as an unlabeled tree with integer leaves. A [tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-of-binary-trees/) could be either labeled, i.e., when nodes are assigned labels or, unlabeled,  i.e., when nodes are not assigned any labels.

Usually, when we speak of trees in the context of computer science we think about labeled trees. And when we speak of labeled trees, we usually are thinking about trees where every node has a label.

Storing data only on leaf nodes is usually inefficient since we have to use a tree with more layers to store the same set of elements since each layer of a k-ary tree can store up to k^(h-1) elements, where `h` is the depth of the layer. And if we will not use inner nodes for storing data, we will end up throwing away k^(h-2) nodes. Despite this, such trees still exist in production and find their uses in some specialized applications, such as [B+ trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) or [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) trees.

Now, let's look into the [unlabeled trees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html). Despite the fact that they are the essence of trees, they are not used very often in the context of computer science and pose of a mathematical interest rather than practical. An unlabeled tree encodes only the structure and nothing more since there is nothing associated with nodes. Unlabeled trees are studied in [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees), could be used to represent molecular structures, and in general to represent different kinds of automata and study isomorphism between structures.

## Tree data structures

### Inductive Definition

There are two approaches to encoding a tree. The canonical way is to use inductive data types, e.g., in OCaml, an unlabeled binary tree is encoded as,

```
type tree = Empty | Tree of tree * tree
```

On the first glance it, again, looks quite useless and bogus. But we can draw an analogy with another simple inductive definition,

```
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat
```

which is the well-known [Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees) encoding of natural numbers. We can easily see, that an unlabeled tree is an extension of Peano numbers (e.g., instead of a unary `Succ` constructor we have binary `Tree` constructor). At the same time we can find out that Peano encoding is nothing more than an unlabeled list, e.g., consider the definition of the list data structure:

```
type 'a list = Empty | List of 'a * 'a list
```

Therefore an unlabeled list, i.e., a list that can't carry anything is still finding its uses, despite the fact, that the only notion that it can encode is its length - which is the essence of the natural numbers - the idea of counting.

The same is true with unlabeled trees, as they denote the simple idea of decision making and each unlabeled tree encodes a distinct element in a space of decisions.

While storing numbers as lists and decisions as trees might look like a waste of space, they still have their uses in the face of [Curry-Howard Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), where each constructible data structure acts as a proof term. And therefore such structures become objects of study in the whole field of automatic theorem proving.

### Representing trees as graphs

It is also [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) that a tree is a special kind of graph, therefore another natural representation of a tree would be a graph, e.g., using an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to represent a graph, we can have the following definition of a tree.

```
type tree = (node * node) list
```

This definition poses a question, what is the `node` type? Indeed, we now need a separate type to bear our graph. In general, we just need to be able to distinguish between two nodes, thus any data type that has an equality operation defined on it will suffice. We can use `int` or `string` for example. Therefore a simple tree with three nodes will be represented as a set of two branches `[1,2; 1,3]` where each branch is an ordered tuple of two nodes.

The main problem with such representation is that it is not tight enough, as it is possible to construct trees that are not trees, e.g., `[1,2; 2,1]` is a well-formed value of our `tree` type, but it is not a tree, since it has a loop. Therefore, in order to preserve the tree structure of our graph we should always check on each insertion whether a loop is created or any other invariant of a tree is broken (e.g., a cross-edge is inserted). Another issue, is that one has to provide a source of distinct integers for each fresh node.

Therefore, the inductive definition of a tree bears a nice property - it is always correct. Every instance of an inductive tree is a tree which is proved by construction. Moreover, in the inductive definition, every new node is actually a fresh new object created in the heap, so they are automatically distinct. Basically, it is the language runtime which is responsible for creating new nodes for us.

However, what is good in the graph representation, and why I'm showing it here, is that it blends the difference between the node and the node label, so it is now very easy to confuse it. Indeed, if we already need to provide some data type to bear nodes (only to make one node distinct from another), then why not to use the same data type to store some labels, i.e., we can use labels themselves as the bearing set, e.g., `["Bil", "Adam"; "Bil", "Eve"]`. And this is indeed a representation that is used quite often in computing. The inductive definition doesn't really provide such freedom.

## Problems with your code

First of all, your data definitions are inconsistent, e.g., the expression

```
 Node( Node(1,2) , Node(2,3) )
```

is not well-defined because you're passing to the `Node` constructor both ints, e.g., `1` or `2`, and values that are constructed by the `Node` constructor, e.g., `Node (1,2)`. Therefore it is not well-typed code, since `Node(1,2)` is having the same type as `1`, which is obviously incorrect.

A tree is a recursive data type, so its constructors should accept values of the same type as the tree itself. Of course, in order to construct a recursive data type, you should have a non-recursive constructor, so that you can enter the recursion, e.g., here is an example of an unlabeled tree

```
type tree = Empty | Node of tree * tree
```

As you can see, there is no place for `int` or any other payload in this definition. This is how an *unlabeled* tree will look like. Contrary to your example, where nodes are parametrized with some integer values.

Now, we are ready to define a labeled tree. It is obviously a different type, therefore it should have different data constructors, e.g.<sup>1</sup>,

```
type ltree = LEmpty | LNode of ltree * int * ltree
```

Now, let's look into an example of an unlabeled and labeled tree, e.g., the example that is closest to your attempt would be

```
let unlabeled = Node (Node (Empty,Empty), Node (Empty, Empty))
```

Now, let's imagine the corresponding labeled tree, where each node is parametrized by the sum of depths of both subtrees, e.g.,

```
let labeled = LNode (LNode (LEmpty, 2, LEmpty), LNode (LEmpty, 2, LEmpty))
```

If I would be writing a function that will translate from the former representation to the latter, then I will start with the `height` function, that will take an unlabeled tree and compute its depth. And then I will write the `translate` function that will recursively map each unlabeled node to a labeled one. Both are trivial, therefore I'm leaving it to you as an exercise.

---

<sup>1)</sup> We've prefixed both our data constructors (starting with the capital letter, e.g., `LEmpty` and `LNode`) and type constructors (starting with a small letter, e.g., `ltree`) with the `L` and `l` letter to distinguish it from the unlabeled tree. It is better to use modules for proper namespacing your constuctors, but this is a completely different story.

Comment: Your tree type is pretty much unusable in this context. There is no place to store data in the leafs as you don't have leafs. Defining a leaf based tree in ocaml is rather ugly as the empty tree has to becomes a special case.

Comment: I  understand the concept of the labled and unlabled trees. However, I'm having problems writing a depth function and using it in a translate function. Could you help with that?

Comment: Ask a specific question, that shows your attempt, i.e., what you have tried to do. Make sure that you've learned how to write functions in OCaml and read the [manual][1], at least the first chapter, before that. (Believe me. you won't have any problems writing the height function after you read it).

[1]: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, I'm not sure about what context are you talking about. In the context of the question, OP wants unlabeled trees. Maybe for the didactic purposes. This is how unlabeled trees are represented in OCaml. How useful they are in practice, is out of the scope (if you want to learn about it, feel free to ask a separate question). Concerning your comment about ugliness of trees in OCaml, I will leave it unnoticed (though thanks for making me smile).

Comment: The question is about unlabeled trees where each leaf holds an integer. He then wants to label internal nodes to hold the sum of the subtrees. In your tree type where would you put the integers?

Comment: And this what my answer is about. The main confusion that OP has (and apparently you too) is that a tree where nodes are labeled with some integer values - is a _labeled_ tree. The _unlabeled_ tree is not having any payload. And he wants to transform an unlabeled tree to a labeled tree with values which are equal to the sum of the corresponding tree _depth_).

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting? If yes, then, please, share, I would be happy to improve the answer.

Comment: @ivg I didn't downvote you, but I think that the reason you were downvoted was that you misinterpreted what OP meant by "unlabeled." In OP's example code, the leaves of the "unlabeled tree" do store numbers. "Labeled" means that the branches of the tree also store numbers.

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like that I've underestimated the problem. Apparently, unlabeled trees need some extra explanation, as OP is not the only one who is misinterpreting them. I will update my answer with a more in-depth explanation of the concept.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with explanations on what tree is.

Comment: Your tree and explanation is still useless. Your unlabled tree holds no data, it only has a structure. Outside theory that is not usefull. Real applications either have trees with data in nodes (your labeled tree) or data in leafs (what the op has as unlabeled tree). Example for a tree with data in the leafs: `type node = Leaf of int | Node of node * node    type tree = Empty | Node of node`. It's not a form that expresses well in ocaml because the empty tree is a special case.

Comment: Well, like it or not, but an unlabeled tree is having this representation. I'm not advocating that they are useful or not. The structure itself encodes a lot of information (and could be used to encode automatons), but in general, I would not expect them to be used in practice. And a tree with data on a leaf is still called a labeled tree. If you want to learn more about trees and their representations in OCaml, please post a question, I will happily provide you a comprehensive answer. Otherwise, this discussion is starting to become too long (and boring).